# Python CSV Line counts are Off

Tags: python-2.7

So some really odd behavior is going on in my python code and not exactly sure why, the line counts of the file being read in and the csv line counts are off:

```
count2 = 0
#Increase CSV field size as we are dealing with large fields
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
with open(nullFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
    print "Sum 2 " + str(sum(1 for row in csvfile))
    csvfile.seek(0)
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter)
    for line in reader:
        count2 +=1
```

The first print is: 7292 and the second print is: 
The count2 is showing 5332, not sure why this would be though. Why is the reader only picking up 7292, I've checked delimiters as well and all normally delimited.

Comment: I suppose it might depend on what is in the file.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you by what is in the file?

Comment: How many lines does the file actually have?  If 7292, can you identify any that don't show up when reading them?  If 5332, can you identify any rows  from csvfile that don't get read by the csv.reader?

Comment: Can you show where `count2` is initialized rather than just how it is incremented? For all I know you have initialized `count2 = -1960` and that is the source of the problem. (The point is not that I suspect you have done this, but to show that you have not yet provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Showed where count2 is initialized. Also to Scott's question, what would be the best way to figure out the missing rows?

Comment: What if there's a line end character which is correctly quoted?  The csv reader will recognize that it's quoted and treat it appropriately, but `for row in csvfile` won't care..

Comment: So the goal of my code was to pull a specific field out and in unix for instance when I do $ cut -f 14 -d "|" X_2015-10-21.csvnoNull.csv | wc -l
7292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV columns can be quoted. A quoted column can have line breaks inside it.

Physically, the file has 7292 `\n` characters.

Allowing for CSV quoting, there are 5332 useful lines of data.

```
"Example","Line\nWith A","Line Break"\n
```

Looks like 2 lines (2 \n characters)

But -- with quoting rules applied -- it's only one row of CSV data.